# Trying to add form data to a database using an Ajax request with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cant quite get my form to add its data to a local database I have setup.

I have a addproducts.php page:

```
<?php
$title = "Products";
include("Header.php");
include("PHPvalidate.php");
?>


<script src="AjaxProduct.js"></script>



<article>
<section>


        <fieldset><legend><span> Add a product to the database </span>    </legend>

        <form  id ="productsform" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">

        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">

        <label> Enter a product name:               <input  type="text"     id="name"           name="name"/>           </label>

        <label> Enter a product quantity:           <input  type="number"   id="quantity"       name="quantity"/>       </label>

        <label> Enter a product description:        <input  type="text"     id="description"    name="description"/>    </label>

        <label> Enter a product price:              <input  type="text"     id="price"          name="price"/>          </label>

        <label> Upload a image of the product:      <input name="image"     accept="image/jpeg"     type="file"></label>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" class="reg"    value="Add Product">

        <div id="check"></div>

        </form>
 </fieldset>
</section>
</article>
```

I then have a ajax fetch request to gather up the data to get ready to be posted to the database:

```
fetch = function () {

var xhr, name, quantity, description, price, target; 

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

target = document.getElementById("check");

name = document.getElementById("name").value;
quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
description = document.getElementById("description").value;
price = document.getElementById("price").value;

var vars =      "name="+name+"&quantity="+quantity+"&description="+description+"&price="+price;


changeListener = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
       target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    } else {
        target.innerHTML = "<p>Something went wrong.</p>";
    }
};

xhr.open("POST", "addSQL.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onreadystatechange = changeListener;
xhr.send(vars);


}

pageLoaded = function() {
var fetchbutton = document.getElementById("submit");
    if(fetchbutton) {
        fetchbutton.addEventListener("click", fetch);
    }
}



 window.onload = pageLoaded;
```

And finally an addSQL.php

That send the data to the database:

```
//Stores all information passed through AJAX into the query
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
   $description = $_POST['description'];
   $price = $_POST['price'];


//Adds information to database
$query = "INSERT INTO products (name, quantity, description, price) VALUES    ('$name','$quantity','$description','$price')";
//Runs the query
$result = $mysqli->query($query) OR die("Failed query $query");
echo $mysqli->error."<p>";

//



?>
```

When i try to add dummy data into the form and submit nothing happens with no errors or anything so Im not sure where the point of failure is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Edit: also now that I look at it, you're vulnerable to SQL injection and an apostrophe in your data will break the query:

```
   $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
   $quantity = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
   $description = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
   $price = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You add some `alert()` in your code to find the error.
    add alert in the every line when you get a value in variable like `alert(vars);` after the assign value in `vars` variable